# Show that the manhattan distance from the origin of an ubiased random walk in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ defines a martingale sequence

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, martingale

> Consider the infinite lattice $N \times N$. A pebble starting at the origin walks at random, each time moving equiprobably to one of its four neighbors. Let $X_i$ be the distance from the origin, measured as the number of hops (Manhattan distance).Show that $X_i$ is a Martingale sequence satisfying the bounded differences condition.

Seeing the bounded difference condition seems simple. However, I don't understand why $X_i$ is a Martingale. If $X_i$ is the manhattan distance from the origin after the $i$-th jump then $X_1 = 1$. But then the Martingale property is violated as follows.
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X_2 \mid X_1] &= \mathbb{E}[X_1 + C_2 \mid X_1] \\
&= X_1 + \mathbb{E}[C_2] \\
&= X_1 + (-1) \frac{1}{4} + 1\cdot \frac{3}{4} \ne X_1
\end{align*}
where $C_2$ is the distance contribution from the second jump (with probability 1/4 the distance decreases by one since we move to the origin and with probability 3/4 the distance increments by one).

Comment: Double-check your argument about the numbers $1/4$ and $3/4.$

Comment: I double checked them but I don't see the issue. WLOG, say that after the first jump the pebble is at (1,0). Then the pebble can move left and the distance decreases by one (hence the $(-1) \frac{1}{4}$). Otherwise the pebble can move up, right, or down and in all of these cases the manhattan distance increases by 1 hence the $1 \cdot \frac{3}{4}$. If the pebble wasn't along the axes $x=0$ or $y=0$ then the 1/4 and 3/4 becomes 1/2 and 1/2 and the argument works out nicely. But for the second jump we will inevitably be on $x=0$ or $y=0$.

Comment: That's a good point.  Evidently one has to work a little harder to make the demonstration ;-).